# T-SQL: How to replace only content of src='data:image/png;base64' attribute on img tag

Tags: html, xml, t-sql, attributes, xhtml

Scenario:
I have asp.net mvc application (case managment system) with very bad performance, I found what it causes the bad performance.

Every activity has fields like: 'Activity Name', 'Activity Status', 'Create by' and etc which are loaded fast from database, but the activities has also two html fields also on database with rich text editors. 
Some users directly paste images from their clipboard to rich text editors and the pasted images are in base64 format like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0xdBXhUR...***HERE ARE 2.4 MILION SYMBOLS...***FvqlEIVCqUUL2ASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
```

some of 'src' atributte of img tags(directly pasted on editor) contain 2.4 milion symbols. I tried to select only one of the two editors with two pasted image inside and the query result was executed is 5.38 sec (two images and some text only for one record). So i decide to find all img tags into those fields and replace their src attribute's content with placeholder image only for closed activities. This would probably positively affect performance.

What should I do: 
I need to replace the content of src attribute of each directly pasted image.

What is common between them: 
Every pasted image string starts with 'img src="data:image/png;base64,'.

How they differ: Some of the img tag are closed by '>' another by '/>'

The issue:
Because I do not know how to find the beginning and end of only the src attribute I tried to select begin with "img src=" and end ("/>") of the img tag.

```
select LEFT(Notes, (CHARINDEX('<img src=',Notes)-1)) +'<PATH TO PLACEHOLDER>' + RIGHT(Notes, Len(notes) - 1 - CHARINDEX('/>', Notes, CHARINDEX('<img src=',Notes))) from assignedActivity
where oid in('7B8086C1-7AF8-457C-8163-109CF167EA5E')
```

I would enjoy any suggestion: 
How can I replace only content of each src attribite?

Here is how it's look some of html editor's content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
      <title>Some activity</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeIAAACxCAYAAAAYhL5OAAAgAElEQVR4AexdBXhUR9d+1y3unhBCggYvbqVAsQqFukG9pdSpUKHupe4uQFvqlEIVCqUUL24JhCQQ93X7n3d2b7LZbA7zewOWEjTzUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with HTML can be tricky, but your document carries the `xhtml` namespace as default. This let's me think, that we can rely on the internal structures to be valid XML.

You can achieve this like here:

--Your sample in a string variable

```
DECLARE @html NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
      <title>Some activity</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeIAAACxCAYAAAAYhL5OAAAgAElEQVR4AexdBXhUR9d+1y3unhBCggYvbqVAsQqFukG9pdSpUKHupe4uQFvqlEIVCqUUL24JhCQQ93X7n3d2b7LZbA7zewOWEjTzUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
   </body>
</html>';
```

--First we have to separate the HTML from the `<!DOCTYPE >` declaration:
--I go the easy way and use the first `>` to computed the right position to cut this in two pieces:

```
DECLARE @PosFirstClosing INT=CHARINDEX('>',@html);
DECLARE @DocType NVARCHAR(300)=SUBSTRING(@html,1,@PosFirstClosing);
```

--Implict conversion will transform your HTML to XML. This is the crucial point.
--If this fails, you cannot use this approach.
--Just try it out and make sure, that your data will always be *XHTML* strictly.

```
DECLARE @xhtml XML=SUBSTRING(@html,@PosFirstClosing+1,4000);
```

--Now we can use XML methods to replace the value of `<img src="xyz">`

```
DECLARE @plcHolder NVARCHAR(MAX)='blah';

SET @xhtml.modify('declare namespace ns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
                   replace value of (/ns:html/ns:body/ns:img/@src)[1] with sql:variable("@plcHolder")');
```

--check the result in the XML viewer

```
SELECT @xhtml;
```

--Now we can rebuild the full html by concatenating the doctype back to the naked html.

```
SET @html=@DocType + CAST(@xhtml AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

--And this is the result:

```
SELECT @html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Some activity</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="blah" alt=""/>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Remarks

This expects just one single image source to be replaced. If there might be more of them, or if the location might be another than `/html/body/img`, you can adjust the `XPath` or we can introduce some `XQuery`. But there was nothing about this in your question. Therefore the easy going...

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Shnugo

The code doesn't fail on

--Implict conversion will transform your HTML to XML. This is the crucial point.
--If this fails, you cannot use this approach.

My question now is: is it possible the variable '@'html to be linked to field?
Like that: DECLARE '@'html NVARCHAR(MAX)= [AssignedActivity].[Notes]?

Comment: @StanislavBalev, this seems to be an entirely new question... Please close this - if it is solved - by ticking the acceptance check and - if you want - by using your right to vote. Then start a new question, try to set up a [mcve] and provide sampe data and expected output. On the first sight you are mixing T-SQL and C# ASP.Net concerns...